# Construct triangle given inradius and circumradius

Tags: geometry, triangles, geometric-construction

If we know the inradius $r$ of a triangle and the circumradius $R$ we can find out the distance between the incircle $I$ and the circumcircle $O$: $OI^2 = R^2-2Rr$. Therefore we can draw the incircle and the circumcircle, and their relative position is fixed. Making some drawings suggests that we can construct $ABC$ in a unique way starting from $R,r$.

> Is there only one triangle $ABC$ (up to isometry) which has inradius $r$ and circumradius $R$? If yes, how do we draw it?

Comment: $$\frac{a+b+c}{abc}=\frac{x+y+z}{xyz}=\frac1{2rR}\qquad,\qquad\{a,b,c\}\neq\{x,y,z\}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can't be true, since there is a three-dimensional space of triangles up to isometry (parametrized by their side-lengths, which only need to satisfy the triangle *inequality*), and you only give me two parameters. A better question is then: what is the family of triangles with the same in- and out- radii.

Comment: I think I've also found a visual counterexample.

Comment: @BeniBogosel On the other hand, if the two centers coincide (so $R=2r$) do you get anything but the equilateral triangle?

Comment: A late answer: if $R=2r$ you can prove that the triangle is equilateral, so it is unique.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a visual answer to my question (constructed *painfully* with Geogebra :) ):[image]

Comment: @Bogosei, could you please tell me how to construct it?

Comment: How to construct the figure? Just construct two circles with $2r<R$, pick a point on the big circle and construct tangents to the small circle. You should tune the distance between the centers in order to have a closed triangle in the end...

Answer (score 4):

The question you asked is the special case of so- called **Poncelet's porism.** It says, that if you have two conics on the plane and one can find a $n-$gon for which one conic is inscribed and the other one is circumscribed in it, then one can find infinitely many such $n-$ gons. See this wikipedia article for the details [Poncelet's porism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poncelet%27s_closure_theorem)