# maximum and minimum perimeter of triangle for fixed circumradius and inradius

Tags: inequality, optimization, euclidean-geometry

In this Question:[construct-triangle-given-inradius-and-circumradius](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/619805/construct-triangle-given-inradius-and-circumradius):

If we know the inradius $r$ and the circumradius $R$ of a triangle, we can't fix the triangle. However, What is the max and min perimeter of these triangles?

We can fix the $OI=\sqrt{2Rr-r^2}$.
In the coordinate set circumcirle to be $x^2+y^2=R^2$, incirle to be $(x-OI)^2+y^2=r^2$.
For Point $A(R \cos\theta,R \sin\theta)$ at the circumcirle , we can calculate the tangent line of incircle $AB$ and $AC$, $B,C$ are also at the circumcirle. and $BC$ is the the tangent line of incircle too.

But the calculation is very complicated. Is there any other method ?

Answer (score 1):

$$(a-b)^2(b-c)^2(c-a)^2=-4r^2\bigl((s^2)^2-2(2R^2+10Rr-r^2)s^2+r(4R+r)^3\bigr)\geqslant0$$

$$2R^2+10Rr-r^2-2(R-2r)\sqrt{R^2-2Rr}\leqslant s^2\leqslant2R^2+10Rr-r^2+2(R-2r)\sqrt{R^2-2Rr}.$$
By Kuing.